# How to implement security in a SOAP webservice?

Tags: web-services, security, ws-security

I am having a SOAP web service. I am using Apache Axis2 to generate the Javabean skeleton from WSDL file and i implemented the functionality.Now i am looking to secure the web service using user name token. What is the option available to do that.

Comment: It is not likely you will get help without posting code and being clear on what you triedand researched and where you failed...

Answer (score 0):

Axis2 is [extensible by using modules](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/modules/index.html) and the security module for Axis2 is called [Rampart](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/). You can engage this module to provide the security functionality.

You might find this article useful: [UsernameToken Authentication with Rampart](http://wso2.org/library/240)

Comment: I found another alternative for this situation. It is possible to use WSO2WSASApplication server. It could be also configured with Tomcat,JBoss etc.